# Can't get domain user inside API - (AngularJs + ASP.NET Framework with Windows authentication)

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, iis, active-directory, windows-authentication

I have this legacy intranet app using an AngularJS SPA consuming an an ASP.NET Web API (on .NET 4.6.1) and I can't manage to get the user authenticated on the domain inside the API, when calls are made by AngularJs.

Inside the API I have situations where I need to get the domain authenticated user. I have tried several combinations inside IIS to set both the AngularJS app and the API with Windows authentication, Impersonation, Authorization Rules. I've read several questions in Stackoverflow and other forums and also searched through several articles but I can't manage to find a solution, I'm feeling helpless in this one.

When I make a direct call to the API using a tool like Postman or through Swagger, `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name` shows the correct authenticated user.

When I make the very same call to the API but through the client, like loading a page that requests data from the API, the user shown in `LogonUserIdentity`, is the one set on the app pool.

The authentication between the client and the API uses bearer token.

Here's my current scenario:

IIS:

- Windows authentication enabled for both the client and the API, Impersonation enabled for both the client and the API
- Authorization rules for ASP.NET and IIS set with allow all users for both Client and API
- Session state in-proc, using cookies and with `UseHostingIdentity` set to false on both Client and API
- Both the client and the API are using the same AppPool, with integrated Pipeline, .NET CLR v4.0,

If there's more info to supply please let me know, I'll update the question with the required info.

Comment: "The authentication between the client and the API uses bearer token". So, did you enable anonymous authentication on IIS?

Comment: If this is working in postman, but not the browser then there is a difference that should be identified between both requests. Can you compare the headers and identify what is different between the two? Can you verify the bearer token in your browser actually belongs to your expected user?

Comment: First of all I do apologise for taking so long to answer, too much stuff happening at the same time.

@LexLi Yeah, I had already tried several combinations between Client and API auth methods, this includes both of them having the same config or alternating Anonymous and Windows Autentication and Impersonation. Also tried different Pool Identities setups. Any idea of how those authentications should be set on the client and on the API?

Comment: First of all I do apologise for taking so long to answer, too much stuff happening at the same time.
@MarkClark as far as I could check, the bearer token is ok and checking the claims brings the correct authenticated user. Users can login in the app I just can't identify the domain authenticated user. Whatever I do, System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity aways brings the AppPool User. I can only get the user logged on the domain if I call the API directly, but when Angular makes that call, the pool user is shown.

Comment: It might be helpful to see what kinds of headers you have on your requests and responses. Again, you need to compare those requests and responses between your tests in postman/swagger vs AngularJS. There is a high probability there is a discrepancy such as swagger implicitly using cookie auth and angularJS using token auth. Not saying that is the specific issue, but finding a diff may illuminate the cause.